# Producing all 3 bit codes which differ only by one digit from a 3 bit codes

Tags: java, arrays

I need to find all the different 3 bit codes. Thi scan be done with 3 nested fro loops.

I want to take this array of bit codes which ive generated and then output all the other codes which differ by only one bit. So im trying to generate an 8*3 2d array. i know that ther are 3 codes that will differ by only 1 digit but i just cannot find a way to code it out.

Here is what i have so far.

```
String[] codes = new String[8];
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
                codes[count] = "" + i + j + k;
                count ++;
            }
        }
    }
    String[] code_1 = new String[3];
    String[][] codesNear = new String[8][3];
    for(int h = 0; h < codesNear.length; h ++){
        for(int i = 0 ; i < codes[1].length() ;i ++){
            if(codes[h].charAt(i) == '1' ){
                if(i != 2)
                    codesNear[h][i] = codes[1].substring(0,i) + "0" + codes[1].substring(i+1);
                else codesNear[h][i] = codes[1].substring(0,i) + "0";
            }
            else {
                if(i != 2)
                    codesNear[h][i] = codes[1].substring(0,i) + "1" + codes[1].substring(i+1);
                else codesNear[h][i] = codes[1].substring(0,i) + "1";
            }
        }
    }
    for (String s : codes) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
    count = 0;
    for(String[] s : codesNear){

        System.out.println("Count" + count + "Code " + codes[count]);
        for(String st : s ){
            System.out.println(st);
        }
        count ++;
    }
}
```

The output is this

```
Count0Code 000
101
011
001
Count1Code 001
101
011
000
Count2Code 010
101
001
001
Count3Code 011
101
001
000
Count4Code 100
001
011
001
Count5Code 101
001
011
000
Count6Code 110
001
001
001
Count7Code 111
001
001
000
```

As you guys can see the out put isnt correct. Like for example for 000 the thre outputs should have been `100 , 010 , 001 not 101 , 011 ,001`

Also would it be possible to take this code and make it able to read some number n and then find all the different possibilities for a n long binary code

Comment: Are you trying to generate Gray-code: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code?

Comment: I am trying to model a math problem it involves a combination of permutations and combinations. I realized i could express the different combination sin binary and as such i thought a computer modelling all the different possibilities would be much easier than doing it by hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to simplify this with a method to convert the lowest 3 bits of the integer to a string.

```
String bitString(int n) {
    return new String("" + ((n>>>2)&1) + ((n>>>1)&1) + (n & 1));
}
```

Then you can use bitwise exclusive or against numbers with a 1 bit in each of the bit positions (1: 001, 2: 010, 4:100). However, it is a bit hard to tell, if this is what you desire from the posted question.

```
String[][] codesNear = new String[8][4];
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    codesNear[i][0] = bitString(i);
    codesNear[i][1] = bitString(i ^ 1);
    codesNear[i][2] = bitString(i ^ 2);
    codesNear[i][3] = bitString(i ^ 4);
}
```

To answer the other part of the question from the edit, yes. However, bitString would have to be modified, as well

```
int numBit = 3;// or whatever number of bits up to the largest 2^numBit that can be stored in int. 
int numCombinations = 1<<numBits;//2^numBits (here numCombinations == 8)
String[][] codesNear = new String[numCombinations][numBits+1];
for(int i = 0; i < numCombinations; i++) {
    codesNear[i][0] = bitString(i,numBits);
    for(int j = 0; j < numBits; j++) {
        codesNear[i][j+1] = bitString(i ^ (1<<j),numBits);
    }
}
```

Then change bitString to this or something similar to build the string. The simplification is shifting the number to strip off the bit by a bitwise and with 1.

```
String bitString(int n, int numBits) {
    StringBuffer ret = new StringBuffer(numBits);
    for(int i = numBits; i > 0; i--) {
          ret.append((n>>>(i-1))&1);
    }
    return ret.toString();
}
```